# Saving data from service worker into text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, service-worker, node-webkit

I am programming an application using Node-Webkit, which utilizes firebase to send and receive messages. I can now send messages between all my apps with no problem.

**My Problem:** When I receive messages in my service worker, I'd like to be able to write/append the received messages to a text file. After much trial and error, I found that...

1. I cannot use "require" in the service worker. For example, i'd normally require 'fs' to work with the file system.
2. I can use ImportScripts() inside the service worker, but importing a javascript file that uses "require" causes the error -  "require is not defined."
3. Attempting to use a File object and writing to it causes the error "Uncaught TypeError: txtFile.writeln is not a function." I have tried to do this multiple ways i've found online, but nothing works. See below:

   var txtFile = new File("[]","afilename.txt");

   txtFile.writeln("some random text");

   txtFile.close();

If i'm correct, it looks like I cannot create a text file from within a service worker and can only do so on my main thread. However, I have no idea how to do pass the data to my main thread.

I would really appreciate help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you can use 'fs' from web worker. For service worker, please file an issue and we'll look into it.

Comment: @RogerWang The file privided/required by google to use the background messaging service is named "firebase-messaging-sw.js", which is a service worker... according to it's name, anyway. Please correct me if i'm wrong, i'm completely new to this side of programming (I'm a C/C++/Java programmer)